# How to use DISTINCT and UNION?

Tags: ms-access

My company imports data from a shared data warehouse into excel. The imported data is spread into 2 worksheets because of the number of rows (100,000). Both worksheets have exact same fields/column headings.

What I've done is created 2 linked tables in access to the 2 worksheets. I've created a union query using UNION ALL to merge both tables into one. There is a field called "current ID". I have split that field into 2 using left() and right() functions to get "case number" and "person number".

Now my question is, how can I make the above table with only distinct values in one field only. 
i.e. I want all the records where the field "case number" is only distinct values.

I tried using UNION instead of UNION ALL but same result because every record is unique.

I want all columns but have DISTINCT applied only to the "case number" field.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want one record per "case number", or **only** records where "case number" is unique (i.e. appears only once in your table)?

Comment: @Andre - one record per case number

Comment: Let me try to explain a little more in detail. There are roughly 92,000 unique records imported into excel. Due to the excel limitation, the 92,000 records are imported in 2 worksheets. The column "current ID" is a 12 digit number. The first 10 digits is a "case number" and the last 2 digits is the "person number". Each case number can have multiple person number. What I need is to list only 1 record per case number. Hope that explains

Comment: What do you do with other record,s that have other person number?

Comment: @marlan - They could be discarded. Basically I want to do a make table query with only 1 record per case number. so the new table will have approximately 41,000 records instead of all 92,000

Comment: well, then, discard the field in both sections of the union. if that doesn't work it means you have another field that with different data per case number.  I like getting distinct values using GROUP BY.

Comment: Thanks Marlan. I got the result using GROUP BY. Also, another question for another table. How would I use LEFT() to truncate the field and use group by in the same query based on the truncated column.